# Issue with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following structure

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><img class='show_detail'></td>
    <tr>
    <tr class='detail'>
        <td>XYZ</td>
    <tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img class='show_detail'></td>
    <tr>
    <tr class='detail'>
        <td>ABC</td>
    <tr>

    </table>
```

I want if class `show_detail` is clicked than next detail row should be display and hide all opened tr with class detail means if first show detail class is clicked than it hide second detail class and show the first detail class.

I tried jquery for this

```
$('.show_detail').click(function() {
    $('.show_detail').next('.detail').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('.show_detail').click(function() {
   var elem = $(this).parents('tr').next('.detail');  // get the next tr with class detail
   $('.detail').not(elem).hide();  // hide all the tr with detail class excluding the next.
    elem.toggle();   // toggle(hide <-> show) the next tr with detail class. 
});
```

Comment: How can I make it as if same show_detail is clicked and any of detail class is opened than it closes open one..

Comment: I am not that master with jquery... Can you please explain 3 and 4 step...?